# RavenDB does not set all the properties on store

Tags: ravendb

I have a really weird scenario where I try to store domain events (I'm trying to learn CQRS and RavenDB at the same time). The basic structure of the documents I try to store are:

```
public interface IDomainEvent { ... }    
public abstract class BaseDomainEvent : IDomainEvent { ... }
public class DomainEventA : BaseDomainEvent { ... }
public class DomainEventB : BaseDomainEvent { ... }
```

Given that I want to store `DomainEventA` and `DomainEventB` in the same collection in RavenDB and I have managed to do so. But the problem is that in the collection I am missing the properties of `DomainEventB`, and not all properties are set even though I have checked that the properties are set before I commit the transaction where I store the objects. The following gist shows a working example of what I want to do: https://gist.github.com/2830093, and the test code that fails me is found in this test: https://github.com/mastoj/TJ.CQRS/blob/ravenfail/TJ.CQRS.RavenEvent.Tests/RavenEventStoreTests.cs that is using this RavenDB code: https://github.com/mastoj/TJ.CQRS/blob/ravenfail/TJ.CQRS.RavenEvent/RavenEventStore.cs.

I really can't get my head around this one.

**EDIT 1:** I can add that in the failing scenario the metadata of the stored object says it is one type but the properties for that type is not stored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I planned to delete or vote for close but I think more than me might experience this problem at some point. I found the solution in my case and it was that the objects I added to RavenDB had a faulty equals method so RavenDB thought that all my objects were the same one. When I added one more property to check in the equals method everything start working as expected.

Comment: Please keep, this answer helped me indirectly find a problem in my code.